# RestSharp How to post object with stream

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm attempting to post an object that contains a stream. Is there a "best" practice to do this with RestSharp? Do I serialize the object to JSON or use a Multipart/form-data?

Sample object:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public Stream File { get; set; }
}
```

Sample RestSharp client:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(fullUrl)
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password),
};
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

// do I use AddFile, AddParameters or both here?

IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

I have used Postman as my PoC but I honestly don't understand the AddParameter part:

```
var client = new RestClient(myURL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter(
    "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", 
    "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"number\"\r\n\r\nmyFile\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"revision\"\r\n\r\nA.4\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"myFile.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n
    ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", 
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```